# send value from ember component to parent template

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ember.js, ember-components, ember-controllers

I want to pass `lat` and `lng` from an ember component to another ember component (`g-map`). My handlebars template:

```
  {{!-- Index.hbs --}}
  <div class="jumbotron-outside">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="display-3">See The Weather Outside :)</h1>
    <p class="lead">This is a simple forecast weather.</p>
    <hr class="my-4">
    <p>Just type everything bellow this input text to get all list of the city</p>
    {{text-autocomplete}}
    <p class="lead">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-default" href="#" role="button" disabled={{isDisabled}}>Search</button>
    </p>
  </div>
  {{g-map lat=lat lng=lng zoom=zoom}}
</div>
```

and this is for my text-autocomplete component:

```
// text-autocomplete/component.js
import Ember from 'ember';

let lat;
let lng;
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    didInsertElement() { //dom can be acessed here :)
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($('input')[0]);
        var parent = this.$('input');
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
            lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
        });
    }
});
```

I want to pass the `lat` and `lng` values from `text-autocomplete` component to the `g-map` component to draw a marker in the google map.

Can anyone solve this? :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create `index.js` controller file and introduce `lat`, `lng` and `zoom` properties. you can pass this properties to components `text-autocomplete` and `g-map`. `text-autocomplete` this component should send actions to controller for updating  new values for `lat` and `lng` because of two way binding it will automatically update in other places too.

index.js controller file,

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    lat:'',
    lng:'',
    zoom:'',
    actions:{
        updateLatAndLng(lat,lng){
            this.set('lat',lat);
            this.set('lng',lng);
        }
    }
});
```

index.hbs

```
{{text-autocomplete lat=lat lng=lng updateLatAndLng=(action 'updateLatAndLng')}}
{{g-map lat=lat lng=lng zoom=zoom}}
```

text-autocomplete.js file

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    didInsertElement() { //dom can be acessed here :)
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($('input')[0]);
        var parent = this.$('input');
        let _this = this;
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
            lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
            _this.sendAction('updateLatAndLng',lat,lng); //here we are sendin actions to controller to update lat and lng properties so that it will reflect in all the other places.
        });
    }
});
```